# Compiling with CMake and ITK error

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, environment-variables, itk

I'm trying to compile some code from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/pierrefillard/coding-blog/createa3dvolumefromseveral2dimages) using CMake and ITK but I'm running into an error.

In CMake I select the source folder at /utilities/ITKImageSeriesToVolume and the build folder at /utilities/ITKImageSeriesToVolume/build. This however gives me an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package):
By not providing "FindITK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ITK", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ITK" with any of
the following names:

ITKConfig.cmake
itk-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ITK_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ITK" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I have tried to set a CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable that points to the root folder of ITK containing ITKConfig.cmake but get the same error.

Hoping someone can help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: After setting ITK_DIR to the root ITK folder I get:

```
CMake Error at D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/ITK/ITKConfig.cmake:48 (include):
include could not find load file:

D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/Build/ITKTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)


CMake Error at D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/Source/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:56 (message):
No such module: "ITKDoubleConversion"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/Source/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:26 (itk_module_load)
D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/Source/CMake/ITKModuleAPI.cmake:84 (_itk_module_config_recurse)
D:/Apps/InsightToolkit/ITK/ITKConfig.cmake:68 (itk_module_config)
CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)
```

Comment: Do exactly as the instructions say. I mean ***Add the installation prefix of "ITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ITK_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.***

Comment: Maybe try the ITK_DIR part. You set that in cmake-gui or ccmake.

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't realize the ITK_DIR part was done inside cmake-gui. After doing that, I get a second error which I will update the main post.

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple fix as mentioned in the ERROR
"Add the installation prefix of "ITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ITK_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ITK" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed."

Make sure your point the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and ITK to your ITK Build Directory. This is assuming you have already build ITK using Cmake atleast once.

Steps
1) Create ITK source folder.

2) Create ITK build folder.

3) Run CMake and select source and build folders.

4) Select respective compiler, and if there are any compiler issues refer this discussion.

5) Configure and generate cmake.

6) Open the build files in build folder with respective IDE (use .sln file if visual studio compilers are used).

7) Build all once on visual studio.

8) Now for your new project use same steps and point CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and ITK to your ITK Build Directory.

And everything should work.
Good Luck!!!

Answer (score -1):

Your ITK build seems to be partly broken. Can you try re-building it? If that does not help, see whether `ITK_USE_SYSTEM_DOUBLECONVERSION` is ON. That means not to build *DoubleConversion* library which comes with ITK but to use the one already present on the system. If it is not present, you have a problem.

Also, unless `ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES` is ON, you have to specifically turn on each module or module group you want to be compiled. In that case, turn on `ITKDoubleConversion`, and any additional modules which that code requires.